# Удалить столбец df

Tags: python

Как удалить столбцы, по условию: удалить столбец, если в последней строке есть цифра 3.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'one'  :[0,0,55,3],
                  'two'  :[0,1,0,0],
                  'three':[0,0,0,3],
                  'four' :[2,0,2,0]})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = df.loc[:, df.iloc[-1] != 3]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ маска на столбцы
```

Действуем от противного, то есть **оставляем** в датафрейме столбцы, в которых последний элемент **не равен 3**.

Но в принципе можно и удалить, просто будет чуть длиннее (а может я просто не знаю короткого способа):

```py
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.iloc[-1] == 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

можно еще отфильтровать:

```
df.filter(df.columns[df.iloc[-1]!=3])
```